# Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type headers

Tags: angular, typescript

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { \[header: string\]: string | string\[\]; } | undefined; context?: HttpContext | undefined; observe?: "body" | undefined; params?: HttpParams | { ...; } | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; responseType?: "json" | undefined; withCredentials?: boolean | undefined; }'.
Property 'headers' is private in type 'HttpHeaders' but not in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { \[header: string\]: string | string\[\]; } | undefined; context?: HttpContext | undefined; observe?: "body" | undefined; params?: HttpParams | { ...; } | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; responseType?: "json" | undefined; withCredentials?: boolean | undefined; }'.

19     return this.http.post(this.url + 'unique-contacts-reached/', Date, this.httpOptions)


node_modules/@angular/common/http/index.d.ts:2585:5
2585     post\<T\>(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
\~\~\~\~
The last overload is declared here.
```

Implementation:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {
  private httpOptions;
  url= 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Authorization' : 'JWT' + ' ' + token});
    this.httpOptions = headers;
  }
  unique_contacts_reached(Date: any){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'unique-contacts-reached/', Date, this.httpOptions)
  }
}
```

I am having the issue in the line:

```
unique_contacts_reached(Date: any){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'unique-contacts-reached/', Date, this.httpOptions)
  }
```

Comment: `this.httpOptions = { headers }`, not headers itself. Headers is one key under `httpOptions`.

Comment: The error is accurate, your `httpOptions` object is not in the correct shape. Please have a look to the official [HTTP guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the third parameter in the [`HttpClient.post()` method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post), it is expected a value with an `object` type that contains a `headers` property, instead of the value with the `HttpHeaders` type.

Modify the `httpOptions` as below:

```
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: headers
};
```